# how can I interrupt a peach query?

Tags: kdb

I have started an instance with 4 slaves using `-s 4`. I ran a heavy query using `peach`.

```
raze myfunction peach list
```

When I go to the q window and try control-c, it doesn't stop the query. Any way to stop the query without having to restart the instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no no guaranteed way to interrupt. Control C works usually but if the process is too busy to check signal then it'll just keep going